# Writing speed in Delta tables significantly increases after copying it in Databricks

Tags: sql, performance, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am merging a PySpark dataframe into a Delta table. The output delta is partitioned by DATE. The following query takes **30s** to run:

```
query = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, PATH_TO_THE_TABLE).alias(
            "actual"
        ).merge(
            spark_df.alias("sdf"),
            "actual.DATE >= current_date() - INTERVAL 1 DAYS 
             AND (actual.feat1 = sdf.feat1) 
             AND (actual.TIME = sdf.TIME) 
             AND (actual.feat2 = sdf.feat2) "
            ,
        ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
```

After copying the content of the Delta to another location, the above query becomes **60 times faster** (i.e. it takes **0.5s** on the same cluster), when using the `NEW_PATH` instead of  `PATH_TO_THE_TABLE`. Here is the command to copy the delta:

```
(spark.read.format("delta").load(PATH_TO_THE_TABLE).write.format(
        "delta"
    )
.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(["DATE"]).save(NEW_PATH))
```

How can I make querying on the first delta as fast as on the new one? I understand that Delta has a versioning system and I suspect it is the reason it takes so much time. I tried to vacuum the Delta table (which lowered the query time to 20s) but I am still far from the 0.5s.

Stack:

- Python 3.7;
- Pyspark 3.0.1;
- Databricks Runtime 7.3 LTS

Comment: what Databricks runtime is used? How the original table was created?

Comment: Databricks Runtime = 7.3 LTS. 


The first table was created with a command similar to the on above:
df.write.format(
        "delta"
    )
.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(["DATE"]).save(NEW_PATH))

Comment: @NoéAchache did you solve this? Was `NEW_PATH` on the same type of disc, because maybe disk write speed differed?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you compare `actual.DATE >= current_date()` as this is most important part of your query please try to run periodically ZORDER sorting delta by thta filed:

```
OPTIMIZE actual ZORDER BY (actual.DATE)
```

You can also try totally vacuum delta:

```
VACUUM actual RETAIN 0 HOURS
```

to do that you need to set s`park.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled false`.

If you don't want benefits of delta (transaction, concurrent writes, timetravel history etc.) you can just use parquet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As specified in the post, I already vacuumed the delta, which helped, but only reduced the query time by ~10s. Regarding ZORDER, it does not work on partition keys (I guess it is already optimized?). Using parquet might indeed be a better idea, however I could not find a python library which allows merging a pyspark df into a parquet?